# iPhone Keyboard layout on webapp

Tags: iphone, html, web-applications

While filling out HTML formulars, the iPhone Keyboard has a black bar on top with the buttons "Back", "Next" and "Done". This bar isn't present on native apps.

I would like to know if there is a way to change the iPhone layout on a webapp in order to hide the bar?

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no intention to verify this but it is my belief that you can not change how iOS puts a field navigation bar when the keyboard is displayed in Safari. I tested in a few web apps out there (notably gmail) and it is there as well.

In iOS app development that bar that Safari puts above the keyboard is a view that the application puts there not something the content (your web app) creates or has access to.

Unfortunately the only way I know of is to create your own iOS native app and have it load the web app. (See mailroom app for an example).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. What you see there is Safari's implementation of entering text in text fields and tabbing through all of them (as there is no TAB key present).